# Lookup formula returns an incorrect answer

Tags: google-sheets

I've written a Google Sheets formula that looks like this:

```
=lookup(I6,
   {"First", "Second", "Third", "Forth", "Fifth"},
   {((D6-E6)*H6), (0.43*H6), ((D6-0.25-E6)*H6), ((D6-E6)*H6), ((D6-E6)*H6)})
```

And the condition for `"First"` works just fine but when I drag the formula down to other cells the formula fails even though `"Second"` exists and so on. What am I missing? The docs say the list has to be "sorted", I'm not quite sure what that means.

[Here's](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rFUblDQBr5nDthqIJnD2b6B2-6JTGchyizpyzdN2oWY/edit?usp=sharing) an example.

Comment: Either `First` or `Second` or `Third` and so on.

Comment: My second column gets $0.00 when it should be like $2,700. H6 is 5,200.00.

Comment: Ha, fair enough. Link is now in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The docs say the list has to be "sorted"

Yes, this is the problem. `lookup` expects the range to be searched to contain a list that is sorted alphabetically (if it contains text strings) or by value (if it contains numbers). If this expectation fails, it will not tell you anything but will likely return a wrong result.

So you have two options.

1. (bad) Sort the search range alphabetically

Of course, you'll also need to rearrange the result range in the same way. The resulting formula is hard to read and maintain.

```
=lookup(I1,
       {"Fifth", "First", "Fourth", "Second", "Sixth", "Third"},
       {((D6-E6)*H6), ((D6-E6)*H6), ((D6-E6)*H6), (0.43*H6), ((D6-0.25-E6)*H6)})
```

2. (good) use [`hlookup`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093375) instead, as the documentation itself suggests

This requires a little adjustment: only one array is given, but it has two rows: first for search, the second for results. The last two arguments indicate that the result is to be taken from the second row, and that the search range is not sorted (false).

```
=hlookup(I1,
       {"First", "Second", "Third", "Forth", "Fifth", "Sixth"; 
       (D6-E6)*H6, 0.43*H6, (D6-0.25-E6)*H6, (D6-E6)*H6, (D6-E6)*H6, L6*H6}, 
       2, false)
```

(You also had a bunch of unnecessary parentheses there)